# flexbox image grid, children have large or small size, don't want any dead space

Tags: css, flexbox

Have a gatsby/contentful portfolio. In contentful, each portfolio item has a boolean value 'featured', either true or false. If the item is featured, I want it to take up 100% width. If the item is not, I want it to be say 33% width. Problem is I don't want dead space. Intended setup below.

The items are coming in from contentful chronologically and then I'm using `.map()` to render them to the page. Have a little ternary saying if `featured===true` then add 'featured' class.

Is there a flexbox solution? Tried shrink and grow, but couldn't get that going, or maybe this is a js sorting algorithm question?

[image: my setup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with grid (and [grid-auto-flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow))

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid: auto-flow / 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.card {
  border: 4px solid black;
  height: 150px;
}

.featured {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card featured"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card featured"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: also in case anyone else is reading this, the terminology I forgot was "masonry". this was very helpful: https://css-tricks.com/piecing-together-approaches-for-a-css-masonry-layout/